# C++ STL: most efficient way to erase the last / first n elements of a std::deque

Tags: c++, performance, stl, std, deque

I am writing a C++ program where I have to maintain a list of offsets (in an array or file) and I am using a `std::deque<size_t>` for this. The list gets filled while reading the file, containing the positions of the last occurrences of a specifiec character - let's say 'a'. So while reading the file, everytime the character 'a' occurs I push its position to the end of the queue.

Now at some points I have to erase all entries in this list that are smaller than a given maximum size (or in other words: that are more than x bytes away from the current reading position). Since the queue is sorted (by the way it is getting created) the most simple approach would probably be to pop the elements off the queue while the value is smaller:

```cpp
void remove_smaller_than(size_t minimum)
{
    size_t element = my_queue.first(); // yes I know, should check if empty here too
    while (element < minimum && !my_queue.empty())
    {
        my_queue.pop_front();
        element = my_queue.first();
    }

}
```

Now the thing is that everytime I have to do this I will have to iterate the queue *from the other side* (for another reason), ending at the position of the *first element that is too far away*. Just to clarify (because this is hard to explain), here again a short snippet:

```cpp
void iterate_over_matches(size_t minimum)
{
    for (auto it = my_queue.rbegin(), end = my_queue.rend(); it != end && *it > minimum; ++it)
        do_something(*it);
}
```

(Something like that, this is only for demonstration).

So my idea was now that if I already have the iterator of the *last valid* (ot rather the *first invalid*) entry, is there a more efficient way to "clip" the deque at this position than popping all entries?

#### TL;DR:

If I have a given iterator of a `std::deque`, is there a more efficient way to erase all elements starting at this iterator up to the end than popping them in a while loop?

Comment: Sounds a lot like [`erase`'s job](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque/erase).

Comment: Side note: Removing items from a container while iterating the container is a major source of bugs. Use the functions built into the container or the [erase-remove idiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase%E2%80%93remove_idiom) to do the work.

Comment: Yes, I guess this will be the best I can get...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the fastest way to erase elements from `std::deque` is indeed the `erase` method, `std::deque` doesn't seem like an ideal data structure for your situation. Since your elements are sorted (they're ever increasing) you can find the index that you need to erase up to in `O(log(n))` time. Unfortunately, `std::deque::erase` has O(n) complexity, so the gains of fast search are totally diminished. We can do better.

Since the elements you store in the data structure don't need to be destructed (as they are just integers), it's possible to make a data structure that erases these elements in constant time. For instance, here's a ring buffer implementation that does it:

```
template <typename T>
class RingBuffer
{
public:
    static_assert(std::is_trivially_copyable_v<T>, "T must be trivially copyable!");
    static_assert(std::is_trivially_destructible_v<T>, "T must be trivially destructable!");

    RingBuffer() :
        m_Items(nullptr),
        m_Capacity(0),
        m_StartIndex(0),
        m_EndIndex(0),
        m_Version(0)
    {
    }

    RingBuffer(const RingBuffer&) = delete;
    RingBuffer& operator=(const RingBuffer&) = delete;

    ~RingBuffer()
    {
        delete[] m_Items;
    }

    void Add(T item)
    {
        m_Version++;

        if (m_EndIndex + 1 == m_StartIndex || (m_EndIndex >= m_StartIndex && m_EndIndex >= m_Capacity && m_StartIndex == 0))
            Grow();

        size_t elementIndex;
        if (m_EndIndex >= m_Capacity)
        {
            elementIndex = 0;
            m_EndIndex = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            elementIndex = m_EndIndex++;
        }

        m_Items[elementIndex] = std::move(item);
    }

    void EraseFirstN(size_t eraseCount)
    {
        m_Version++;

        auto count = size();
        assert(eraseCount <= count);

        if (eraseCount == count)
        {
            m_StartIndex = m_EndIndex = 0;
            return;
        }

        m_StartIndex += eraseCount;
        if (m_StartIndex >= m_Capacity)
            m_StartIndex -= m_Capacity;
    }

    size_t size() const
    {
        if (m_EndIndex >= m_StartIndex)
            return m_EndIndex - m_StartIndex;

        return m_Capacity - m_StartIndex + m_EndIndex;
    }

    struct Iterator : std::iterator<std::random_access_iterator_tag, T>
    {
        Iterator() :
            m_Container(nullptr),
            m_Index(0),
            m_Version(0)
        {
        }

        Iterator(RingBuffer<T>* container, size_t index, size_t version) :
            m_Container(container),
            m_Index(index),
            m_Version(version)
        {
        }

        Iterator& operator+=(ptrdiff_t value) { m_Index += value; return *this; }
        Iterator& operator-=(ptrdiff_t value) { m_Index -= value; return *this; }

        T& operator*() { assert(m_Version == m_Container->m_Version); return (*m_Container)[m_Index]; }
        const T& operator*() const { assert(m_Version == m_Container->m_Version); return (*m_Container)[m_Index]; }

        T* operator->() { assert(m_Version == m_Container->m_Version); return &(*m_Container)[m_Index]; }
        const T* operator->() const { assert(m_Version == m_Container->m_Version); return &(*m_Container)[m_Index]; }

        T& operator[](const int& index) { assert(m_Version == m_Container->m_Version); return (*m_Container)[m_Index + index]; }
        const T& operator[](const int& index) const { assert(m_Version == m_Container->m_Version); return (*m_Container)[m_Index + index]; }

        Iterator& operator++() { m_Index++; return *this; }
        Iterator& operator--() { m_Index--; return *this; }
        Iterator operator++(int) { return Iterator(m_Container, m_Index++, m_Version); }
        Iterator operator--(int) { return Iterator(m_Container, m_Index--, m_Version); }
        ptrdiff_t operator-(const Iterator& other) const { assert(m_Container == other.m_Container && m_Version == other.m_Version); return static_cast<ptrdiff_t>(m_Index - other.m_Index); }
        Iterator operator+(const ptrdiff_t& index) const { return Iterator(m_Container, m_Index + index, m_Version); }
        Iterator operator-(const ptrdiff_t& index) const { return Iterator(m_Container, m_Index - index, m_Version); }
        friend Iterator operator+(const ptrdiff_t& index, const Iterator& other) { return other + index; }
        friend Iterator operator-(const ptrdiff_t& index, const Iterator& other) { return Iterator(other.m_Container, index - other.m_Index, other.m_Version); }

        bool operator==(const Iterator& other) const { assert(m_Container == other.m_Container && m_Version == other.m_Version); return m_Index == other,m_Index; }
        bool operator!=(const Iterator& other) const { assert(m_Container == other.m_Container && m_Version == other.m_Version); return m_Index != other.m_Index; }
        bool operator>(const Iterator& other) const { assert(m_Container == other.m_Container && m_Version == other.m_Version); return m_Index > other.m_Index; }
        bool operator<(const Iterator& other) const { assert(m_Container == other.m_Container && m_Version == other.m_Version); return m_Index < other.m_Index; }
        bool operator>=(const Iterator& other) const { assert(m_Container == other.m_Container && m_Version == other.m_Version); return m_Index >= other.m_Index; }
        bool operator<=(const Iterator& other) const { assert(m_Container == other.m_Container && m_Version == other.m_Version); return m_Index <= other.m_Index; }

    private:
        RingBuffer<T>* m_Container;
        size_t m_Index;
        size_t m_Version;
    };

    Iterator begin()
    {
        return Iterator(this, 0, m_Version);
    }

    Iterator end()
    {
        return Iterator(this, size(), m_Version);
    }

    T& operator[](size_t index)
    {
        assert(index < size());

        index += m_StartIndex;
        if (index >= m_Capacity)
            index -= m_Capacity;

        return m_Items[index];
    }

private:
    void Grow()
    {
        auto newCapacity = std::max(m_Capacity * 2, m_Capacity + 4);
        auto newItems = new T[newCapacity];

        if (m_EndIndex >= m_StartIndex)
        {
            memcpy(newItems, m_Items + m_StartIndex, (m_EndIndex - m_StartIndex) * sizeof(T));
            m_EndIndex = m_EndIndex - m_StartIndex;
        }
        else
        {
            memcpy(newItems, m_Items + m_StartIndex, (m_Capacity - m_StartIndex) * sizeof(T));
            memcpy(newItems + m_Capacity - m_StartIndex, m_Items, m_EndIndex * sizeof(T));

            m_EndIndex = m_Capacity - m_StartIndex + m_EndIndex;
        }

        delete[] m_Items;

        m_StartIndex = 0;
        m_Items = newItems;
        m_Capacity = newCapacity;

    }

private:
    T* m_Items;
    size_t m_Capacity;
    size_t m_StartIndex;
    size_t m_EndIndex;
    size_t m_Version;
};
```

Erasing from this data structure is much, much faster than using `std::deque`. Here's the benchmarking code I used:

```
constexpr size_t kCount = 100 * 1000 * 1000;

size_t everIncreasingIndex = 0;
size_t elementToEraseUpTo = 5674112;

std::deque<size_t> deque;
RingBuffer<size_t> ringBuffer;

std::cout.setf(std::ios::fixed);
std::cout.precision(5);

for (size_t u = 0; u < 10; u++)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < kCount; i++)
    {
        deque.push_back(everIncreasingIndex);
        ringBuffer.Add(everIncreasingIndex);

        everIncreasingIndex++;
    }

    {
        Stopwatch stopwatch;

        auto it = std::lower_bound(deque.begin(), deque.end(), elementToEraseUpTo);
        deque.erase(deque.begin(), it);

        auto elapsed = stopwatch.ElapsedSeconds();
        std::cout << "std::deque took " << elapsed * 1000 << " ms." << std::endl;
    }

    {
        Stopwatch stopwatch;

        auto it = std::lower_bound(ringBuffer.begin(), ringBuffer.end(), elementToEraseUpTo);
        ringBuffer.EraseFirstN(it - ringBuffer.begin());

        auto elapsed = stopwatch.ElapsedSeconds();
        std::cout << "Ring buffer took " << elapsed * 1000 << " ms." << std::endl;
    }

    elementToEraseUpTo *= 2;
}
```

On my machine, here are the results:

```
std::deque took 6.43080 ms.
Ring buffer took 0.00220 ms.
std::deque took 6.40030 ms.
Ring buffer took 0.00170 ms.
std::deque took 12.83000 ms.
Ring buffer took 0.00160 ms.
std::deque took 25.61430 ms.
Ring buffer took 0.00240 ms.
std::deque took 51.16480 ms.
Ring buffer took 0.00280 ms.
std::deque took 102.56710 ms.
Ring buffer took 0.00270 ms.
std::deque took 205.54640 ms.
Ring buffer took 0.00250 ms.
std::deque took 411.39580 ms.
Ring buffer took 0.00250 ms.
std::deque took 170.58990 ms.
Ring buffer took 0.00300 ms.
std::deque took 98.51280 ms.
Ring buffer took 0.00230 ms.
```

Answer (score 2):

Because this is a container of discrete elements, any sort of removal of those elements will involve iterating over them. Even the standard library's functions for erasing elements do use loops internally.

If the number of elements to remove was constant (for instance, if you knew that there is always 5 elements to remove), then you could omit loops, and just write 5 separate instructions, and that would be tiny bit more efficient (you would avoid conditional jump instructions generated by a loop).

Comment: Since `deque` is a list of blocks, it may be able to drop whole blocks at a time instead of iterating through every single element. Whether it does this or not, I can't say. Anything with non-trivial destruction definitely needs to do all the destruction work, but a block of integers... Poof. Gone.

Comment: That's exactly why I had the idea originally. But I guess in this case the deque template must have been specialized for simple datatypes only for this one purpose - probably not the case.

Comment: With a continuous array (C-style array), you can only `delete` the whole thing at once. You could implement your own memory manager that would allow deleting only part of the allocated memory block (only at ends), but std::queue is not a continuous block of memory, but separate elements. And logically separate elements (even if stored in memory one after another), are allocated separately, which means separate allocation information (address and size) for each of those elements. Even if you wanted to drop _n_ such elements at once, you would have to first iterate (in a loop!) over their sizes.

Answer (score 2):

> If I have a given iterator of a std::deque, is there a more efficient
> way to erase all elements starting at this iterator up to the end than
> popping them in a while loop?

Yes – call the [`erase` member function of `std::deque`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque/erase) using the override that takes two iterator arguments. The first would be your "given iterator" and the second would be the `end()` iterator for your deque object.

Here's an example based on that given in the linked cppreference page:

```cpp
#include <deque>
#include <iostream>

void print_container(const std::deque<int>& c)
{
    for (auto& i : c) {
        std::cout << i << " ";
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
}

int main()
{
    std::deque<int> c{ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
    print_container(c);
    auto it = c.begin();
    while (*it != 5) ++it;
    c.erase(it, c.end()); // Erase from a given iterator to the end of the container
//  c.erase(c.begin(), it); // Or to erase the other part
    print_container(c);
    return 0;
}
```

Whether or not an STL implementation makes this 'more efficient' than iterating yourself through the container will depend on several factors (like the nature of the contained objects), but a quick look at the MSVC/clang-cl implementation suggests that the STL can use a call to `std::move()` to achieve this (for primitive contained types, at least).